# Xquery module to convert decimal to hex/octal or any other base based on input parameter

Tags: xquery

I want a function that take 2 parameters,

first param is input decimal,

second param is base (16 for hex conversion, 8 for octal conversion)

The function should return the converted value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it yourself using a recursive user-defined function (and a second one as a convenience wrapper):

```
declare function local:to-base($value as xs:integer, $base as xs:integer) as xs:string {
  if($base lt 2 or $base gt 16) then error((), 'Base must be between 2 and 16, found ' || $base)
  else if($value ge 0) then local:to-base($value, $base, ())
  else '-' || local:to-base(-$value, $base, ())
};

declare function local:to-base($value, $base, $out) {
  let $last := $value mod $base,
      $rest := $value idiv $base
  let $new-out := (if($last lt 10) then $last + 48 else $last + 55, $out)
  return if($rest eq 0) then codepoints-to-string($new-out)
  else local:to-base($rest, $base, $new-out)
};
```

You can invoke it just as you describe:

```
local:to-base(511, 16), (: yields '1FF' :)
local:to-base(-123, 3)  (: yields '-11120' :)
```